# for loop in one line (for python -c)

Tags: python, python-3.x, console

I want to use `python -c` to remove wheel files from the `dist/` directory in my project. (*)

Actually, I use the following command:

```sh
python -c "from pathlib import Path; [p.unlink() for p in Path('dist').glob('Pascal_Scraper-*.whl')]"
```

Is there a shorter/cleaner way to do that?

---

(*) the setuptools command `python setup.py rotate --keep=1 --match=.whl` doesn't work for me.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `python -c` for this? I think `rm dist/Pascal_Scaper-*.whl` would be clearer.

Comment: Because `rm` is not available on Windows.

Comment: `del dist\Pascal_Scraper-*.whl` ? Or is this supposed to be crossplatform?

Comment: Cross-platform, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use python for being crossplattform and if you need to do this in one line then this is the way to go, yes.

For some reason

Alternatives to consider:

- put the code in a file so you can make it more readable
- create a Makefile and run this under a target (like `clean:`)
- use [os instead of pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#correspondence-to-tools-in-the-os-module) to see if you like that better (pathlib is fine, though)
- use `map` and a `lambda` instead of list comprehension, to see if you like that better (probably not though)

I would have expected that a one-line for loop would work, but it doesn't seem to in `python -c` when there is a command before it.

I think there is no much cleaner solution

Comment: This command should live in a `tox.ini` file. So a makefile is not necessary.

Comment: `map` is an iterator, so I would use it like this: `list(map(Path.unlink, Path('dist').glob('Pascal_Scraper-*.whl')))` which is not very clear, right?

Comment: I think you could make an argument for map, but if it is not clear for you then it is not a good solution for you.